# What's the difference between these two types of compression fittings?

Tags: plumbing, fastener

In my piles of random hardware I have a pile of brass compression fittings for water lines. I have two different types of compression nuts. One has a sleeve inside it. The other doesn't. What's the difference?

[image: Top of nuts]
[image: Bottom of nuts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both do the same thing except the one on the left has an integral compression ring (ferrule) and the one on the right uses a separate ferrule (which is not in your picture).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one on the left tightens the "compression ring" around a (usually copper, but could be plastic) tube.  The one on the right tightens itself onto the "coned" (sorta' phallic-shaped) end of a pipe.